# jSerialComm SerialPort.getCommPorts() throwing java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a JComboBox list all serial ports that have something plugged in but whenever I try to get a list of the ports my application spits out an error and quits.

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at me.joezwet.eit.picontroller.PiController.main(PiController.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.<clinit>(SerialPort.java:70)
... 1 more
```

PiController.java:49:

```
SerialPort[] portNames = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
```

SerialPort:70: (part of jSerialComm library)

```
for (File listing : directoryListing)
```

From what I can see the list `directoryListing` isnt being initialized so I found where the variable is being declared:

```
File directoryListing[] = directory.listFiles();
```

I've spent around 3 hours trying to find a fix so I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: `File.listFiles()` returns null when the file object is not a directory, or some kind of error happens. Can you post the output for `directory.canRead()` and `directory.isDirectory()` ?

Comment: Note for Linux users: Serial port access is limited to certain users and groups in Linux. To enable user access, you must open a terminal and enter the following commands before jSerialComm will be able to access the ports on your system. Don't worry if some of the commands fail. All of these groups may not exist on every Linux distro. (Note, this process must only be done once for each user):

`sudo usermod -a -G uucp username
sudo usermod -a -G dialout username
sudo usermod -a -G lock username
sudo usermod -a -G tty username`

Comment: What OS and Java version, please?

Comment: *I've spent around 3 hours trying to find a fix* but now obviously too busy to reply to people who are trying to help you

Comment: its currently running on a windows 10 pc, but Im gonna move it over to a raspberry pi 3 B when its done. I'm using java 9.0.4 and just realized this might be why its not working. edit: tested on 8u171 which still didnt work

Comment: @Kenpachi `directory` seems to be the java temp dir https://imgur.com/N4We09s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason java couldn't access the windows temp directory, so all I had to do was open `c:\windows\temp` in file explorer, run the jar and it worked.